# c# linq 'potentially' grouping and differences

Tags: c#, linq

i am not sure how to tackle this problem.  i have a class, below, to represent the data being pulled from two websites.  I want to compare the difference between 'Site1 TradePrice to Site2 Price' AND 'Site2 TradePrice to Site1 Price'

```
public class Card
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Site {get;set;}
  public decimal TradePrice {get;set;}
  public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

Here is an example list which contains the same 'card' from two different 'sites'.

```
List<Card> cards = new List<Card)
{
  new Card() { Name="card1", Site="site1", TradePrice=8, Price=12 },
  new Card() { Name="card1", Site="site2", TradePrice=5, Price=10 },
  new Card() { Name="card2", Site="site1", TradePrice=13, Price=16 },
  new Card() { Name="card2", Site="site2", TradePrice=4, Price=5 },
  new Card() { Name="card3", Site="site1", TradePrice=2, Price=4 },
  new Card() { Name="card3", Site="site2", TradePrice=3, Price=6 }
}
```

The new list returned would show something like this

```
{ Name='card1', TradePrice=8, Price=10, Diff=2 } //site1 to site2
```

Is this possible with linq?  i am leaning towards Grouping BUT not sure how to accurately make this happen.  Suggestions?

Comment: Is this not just projection of `Diff = Price - TradePrice`? Where's the grouping here?

Comment: Use a JOIN on card1.name equals card2.name

Comment: yes that is exactly it BUT i over simplified the original list containing data.  essentially the list will have a Site pair, now i need to find the diff between that matching pair

Comment: @Aaron.S Can you provide improved example input and output data?

Comment: @cdhowie i added more example date to the list of cards

Comment: Are you sure that you want two `card1` entries in the results? Why not having a single `card1` result entry, combining info from both sites?

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias yes that is exactly what i want ONE card1 result.  Sorry i got type happy and made a typeo with my example

Comment: What should happen if the source has more than two `card1` entries? Is this a possibility?

Comment: How do you choose which TradePrice from card1 or card2?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias YES it is possible that more than one card will exist BUT there are other conditions i have removed from this over simplified example, it will contain one card from each site and they will match

Comment: @RobertHarvey a master SITE will be chosen for comparison and only TWO sites can be compared at once

Comment: Could you update your question correcting the expected result in case of two cards with same name, and also provide an example of the expected result in case of three cards with same name?

Comment: Another case that may warrant an example of expected result, is the case of a card name with a single representation in the source list!

Answer (score 2):

I'll take my lumps with this one...

You can group by the card name which will give you a collection of groups of two cards. From there you can select down into a `DiffCard`, for example. Like so:

```
// Usage
var answer = cards
    .GroupBy(c => c.Name)
    .SelectMany(ToDiffs)
    .ToList(); // A list of DiffCards

// or maybe?
var answer =
    from card in cards
    group card by card.Name into siteGroup
    let o = siteGroup.ElementAt(0)
    let t = siteGroup.ElementAt(1)
    select new List<DiffCard> { new DiffCard(o, t), new DiffCard(t, o) } into diffs
    from diff in diffs
    select diff;

public class DiffCard
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal TradePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Diff => Math.Abs(TradePrice - Price);

    public DiffCard(Card one, Card two)
    {
        Name = one.Name;
        TradePrice = one.TradePrice;
        Price = two.Price;
    }
}


IEnumerable<DiffCard> ToDiffs(IGrouping<string, Card> group)
{
    var one = group.ElementAt(0);
    var two = group.ElementAt(1);
    var diffs = new List<DiffCard>
    {
        new DiffCard(one, two),
        new DiffCard(two, one)
    };
    foreach (var diff in diffs)
    {
        yield return diff;
    }
}
```